# Is it possible to write Flutter applications with ES6 JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flutter

Would it be possible to write Flutter applications with ES6 JavaScript (or other version) instead of using Dart ?

Comment: I don't think so. Transpilation is always a diffucult task, especially as Dart is statically typed (?)